# Did the word "citione" meaning "bump in the head" exist in Latin?

Tags: etymology, word-request, noun, spanish

In the Spanish language site someone asked about the [etymology of the word *chichón*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28464/12637) (link in Spanish), meaning *bump* (typically in the head as a result of a hit). The most common theory is that it is just an augmentative for *chicha*, an informal version for *flesh*. But then I found this in a book from 1611:

[image: Rosal, 1611]

This text properly defines what a *chichón* is, but then it states that it comes from Latin *citione*, a word with the same meaning, derived from the verb *cire*.

I have not found the word *citione* in any Latin dictionaries. So in order to know the reliability of this book, I ask: did the word *citione* exist at any time in the history of the Latin language? If not, what were the words used in Latin for *bump* (as a blow in the head)?

Answer (score 4):

My guess, for what it's worth, is that *chichon* originates from the verb *cieo, cire,civi, citum*, (which loses the *e* in compounds *excio, accio* etc.). The verb's general sense, like that of its compounds, is to agitate, stir up, cause, stimulate and so on.

It's not hard to imagine a noun *citio* being formed from the supine stem to mean a 'blow', 'incentive' etc. — or even the 'bump' suggested in the question.

Comment: Nice finding! It's worth underscoring what you already said implicitly, that 1) the infinitive matches that in the quoted passage and 2) _citio_ would be a regular construction from that verb

Comment: @Rafael. "Would be" is not a good answer to "does it exist".

Comment: @fdb  Let's not tie ourselves up in knots over this, but I would say that Rafael's conditional is good form, introducing as it does a satisfying element of doubt in a place where where have no certain authority.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the Latin word is actually *caesio*, which means cutting, wounding, or killing and comes from *caedere*.
This seems to be reasonably close to the meaning in Spanish.

In compounds the *ae* turns into *i*, as in *occidere* and *occisio*.
This explains how one might end up with *cisio*.
Perhaps it was by analogy to the prefixed forms, or perhaps the same weakening applied to the original verb at some later point.

In some dialects of medieval Latin *-tio* and *-sio* are pronounced the same, so *cisio* can turn into *citio*.
And when you take the ablative, you end up with *citione*.

Perhaps the cited verb *cire* is a corruption of *caedere*.
This would not be a surprising Romance development, but I have never seen such a verb in Latin.

Comment: The word _occidere_ in fact reminds me of Italian _uccidere_ 'to kill', and _ucciso_ 'killed'. I understand that the development of _citione_ here is just a theory but there are no proofs that such a word existed. Thanks for your answer!